# Does one component's css apply to other component in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have two components in react JS with two different css, and I import first css into first component and second css to second component.

Does my first css apply in second without even importing??

Comment: because all css get build into one css file when u build/run project

Comment: Can you please add your css / component code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to edit your answer to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If your css is relevant to a class name in one component. Then when you import that component to another parent etc. It will still be the same. Just ensure you don’t have identical classNames.

Comment: Thanks for your help... BTW I was using different class names... And i solved it by giving differnent classNames for different tags which finally solved the problem.. and I also used style objects which i wrote inside on object and exported in inside my component without even using an external .css file